# debugging error "interpreter `mi2' unrecognized" with eclipse

Tags: c, gdb, eclipse-cdt

Debugging with eclipse ide I get this error:
"Error in services launch sequence. Interpreter `mi2' unrecognized."
This was all working a month ago so for some reason it has stopped.
I know mi2 is something to do with GDB.

Code is built using gcc-8.3.0-2019.08.0,  using Freedom Studio SiFive Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Development
Version: 4.12.0.2019-08-2

I realise this is a bit niche so any suggestions welcome

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Recreate Project using Freedom-E SDK Software Project for my project - which was e310 arty (I had selected the wrong one in starting the project).
When debugging use configuration for "SiFive GDB OpenOCD Debugging."

This seemed to work.